# OutputDebugString output "??????" instead string

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I try to debug some values in C in MSVC 2013 and decided to use this function first time.
I don't know, but I receive only

`"??????????????"`

in the ouput window. I checked the Debugging type, tryed to both state Auto/Mixed, but the same. Look it:

```
#include <windows.h>
...
OutputDebugString(_T("HELLO!\n"));
...
```

What do you think about it? Thanks!

Comment: did you try to output the string without the _T("") ?

Comment: Right now I tryed 'OutputDebugString("HELLO\n");' and 'OutputDebugString("hello\n");'  but the same. Also I restarted MSVC with Mixed type of debugging. Nope.((

Comment: Numbers as string works perfect!

Comment: Hmm. May be a reason is it string in .lib file, may be something else, but when I put it in main function in C++ it works perfect.

Comment: Please provide MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it!

```
OutputDebugStringA("Hello!\n");
```

Works perfect! (MSVC2013, WIN7, 64)